# Need to find a critical point of a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

This question stems from [an old 538 puzzle involving a duck in a pond and a fox patrolling the edge of the pond](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/will-the-dog-catch-the-duck/).

I was able to setup a system of ODEs that probably do not have an explicit solution:

```
pd = {rd[t] Cos[thetad[t]], rd[t] Sin[thetad[t]]}
pf = {r Cos[thetaf[t]], r Sin[thetaf[t]]}
thetadir = FullSimplify[ArcCos[pd.(pf - pd)/(Norm[pd]*Norm[pf - pd])]]

DSolve[{
   rd'[t] == vd*Sin[thetadir],
   thetad'[t] == vd/rd[t]*Cos[thetadir],
   thetaf'[t] == vf/r,
   rd[0] == 10^-5,
   thetad[0] == Pi,
   thetaf[0] == 0
 },
 {rd, thetad, thetaf}, t,
 Assumptions -> {
   t ∈ Reals, t >= 0, 
   r ∈ Reals, r > 1,
   vd ∈ Reals, vd > 0,
   vf ∈ Reals, vf > vd,
   rd[t] ∈ Reals,
   thetaf[t] ∈ Reals,
   thetad[t] ∈ Reals
 }
]
```

The desire is that I find `vf/vd` in terms of $r$ such that `rd == r` when `thetad == thetaf`.  This will give the upper bound of the speed of a fox that a duck can escape.

The behavior of $rd$ is monotonic and unbounded when $vf/vd$ is less than this value.  And it contains a local maximum when $vf/vd$ is greater than this value.  (When it is equal to this value, then we get a divide by zero because `Norm[pf - pd] == 0`).

I can use `NDSolve` if I give initial values for `vd`, `vf`, and `r`, however, I don't know how to iterate through values of `vd`, `vf`, and `r` to where I can "zero in" on this critical point and find the relationship between these three values.  Can I get some insight?

Comment: You might benefit from `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: Can't you write explicitely the criticality conditions, by solving the system of "derivatives == 0", for the unknowns `vd`, `vf`, and `r`?

Comment: note since `thetaf'[t]` is constant you can remove that from the system of equations and simply use `thetaf=vf/r t`

Comment: FWIW the puzzle has a trivial (lower bound) solution that the duck can beat the fox if `vf/vd < 1 + Pi`.  The actual solution is something more than that..

Comment: Yeah, I found the correct solution.  I was just chasing this idea to see what I got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalizing by setting r = 1 and vd (the speed of the duck) to 1, and then using ParametricNDSolve, provides functions in vf (speed of the fox) and t for rDuck, thetaDuck, and thetaFox. Findroot solves for rDuck = 1 (where the fox is) and thetaDuck = thetaFox.

The fox travels at a speed of 2.34 to meet the duck in 1.2, in whatever units are in use.

```
pd={rd[t] Cos[thetad[t]],rd[t] Sin[thetad[t]]} ;
pf={r Cos[thetaf[t]],r Sin[thetaf[t]]};
 thetadir=FullSimplify[ArcCos[pd.(pf-pd)/(Norm[pd]*Norm[pf-pd])]];
normalization={r->1,vd->1};
{frd,fthetaf,fthetad}={rd,thetad,thetaf}/.ParametricNDSolve[{rd'[t]==vd*Sin[thetadir],thetad'[t]==vd*Cos[thetadir],thetaf'[t]==vf/r,rd[0]==10^-5,thetad[0]==Pi,thetaf[0]==0}/.normalization,{rd,thetad,thetaf},{t,0,100},{{vf,.5,5}}];
sol2=FindRoot[{frd[vf][t]==1,fthetad[vf][t]==fthetaf[vf][t]},{{vf,2},{t,50}}]
(* {vf\[Rule]2.3448618677572135`,t\[Rule]1.2171083713163402`} *)
Plot[{frd[vf][tt],fthetad[vf][tt],1,fthetaf[vf][tt]}
/.sol2//Evaluate,Evaluate[{tt,0,t}/.sol2],PlotLegends->{"Rduck","ThetaDuck","Rfox","ThetaFox"}]
```

[image]

I do find it a bit puzzling that the fox seems to reverse course!